# jQuery call to Web API not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

- .NET 4.61, WebForms, WebAPI 2, C#

I have the following AJAX call to a WebAPI controller:

```
$.ajax('/api/search', {
    type: 'POST',  
    data: { '': searchText },  // data to submit
    done: function (data, status, xhr) {
        alert('here');
        console.log(data);
        $('#search-results').append('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + data);
    },
    fail: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        alert('here2');
        $('#search-results').append('Error' + errorMessage);
    }
});
```

and the API Contoller code:

```
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public FindViewModel Find([FromBody] string aSearchText)
    {
        //Code omitted that does the actual population of the result

        //Return them alphabetically
        result.Items = result.Items.ToList().OrderBy(r => r.DisplayText).ToList();

        return result;
     }  
}
```

however I never get into the done or error promises from the original AJAX call. ie no Alerts. Firebug shows a 200 reposonse with the data I expect:

[image]

What am I missing here to get into the done/fail promises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done) and [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail) are not `$.ajax()` options. You can chain `.done()` and `.fail()` to `$.ajax()` call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/search',
    type: 'POST',  
    data: { '': searchText }  // data to submit
})
.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
    alert('here');
    console.log(data);
    $('#search-results').append('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + data);
})
.fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    alert('here2');
    $('#search-results').append('Error' + errorMessage);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong names for `success` and `error` callbacks:

```
$.ajax('/api/search', {
    type: 'POST',  
    data: { '': searchText },  // data to submit
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        alert('here');
        console.log(data);
        $('#search-results').append('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + data);
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        alert('here2');
        $('#search-results').append('Error' + errorMessage);
    }
});
```

Also:

> What am I missing here to get into the done/fail promises?

You are using **callbacks** in this situation, note that **promises** are a different thing. Please take a look at the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation for more information.

Comment: An alternative would be to chain `.done()` and `.fail()` methods your `.ajax()` method call.

Comment: @SimianAngel Yes, that's right. I'd use promise chains myself, but my suggested answer involves less code refactor.